# MVC4 Code first approach, how to fix the following?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am getting the following error
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UserRoles_Roles_Source' in relationship 'UserRoles_Roles'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

My entities and the associated mappings are defined as follows,

```
public class UserProfile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
           UserUserRoles = new List<UserRoles>();       
        }         

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }      
        public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> UserUserRoles { get; set; } 
    }

 public class Roles
    {
        public Roles()
        {
            RoleUserRoles = new List<UserRoles>();
        }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> RoleUserRoles { get; set; }
    }

  public class UserRoles
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }


        public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
        public virtual Roles Roles { get; set; }

    }

//Mappings

  public UserProfileMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.UserId);

            // Properties
            Property(t => t.UserName)
                .HasMaxLength(56);     

            // Table & Column Mappings
            ToTable("UserProfile");
            Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            Property(t => t.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
        }

public class RolesMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Roles>
    {
        public RolesMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.RoleId);

            // Properties
            Property(t => t.RoleName)
                .HasMaxLength(256);       

            // Table & Column Mappings
            ToTable("webpages_Roles");
            Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
            Property(t => t.RoleName).HasColumnName("RoleName");
        }
    }

public class UserRolesMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRoles>
    {
        public UserRolesMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.UserId);
            HasKey(t => t.RoleId);          

            // Table & Column Mappings
            ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
            Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");


            // Relationships              
            HasRequired(t => t.User)
                .WithMany(t => t.UserUserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);

            HasRequired(t => t.Roles)
                .WithMany(t => t.RoleUserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
        }
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but a combined primary key should be constructed as `HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId });`

Comment: Jeroen - thanks mate, that was the issue

Comment: I'm glad to help. I'll post it as an answer so you can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments:

A combined primary key should be constructed as `HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId });`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a many-to-many relation between models. In that case you do not need the class `UserRoles`, it will be generated by EF when using this scenario:

```
public class User
{
  // other properties

  public virtual IList<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}

public class Role
{
  // other properties

  public virtual IList<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

However, if you do want the `UserRoles` model to for instance store additional information you need to make the mapping manually in for example the `OnModelCreating()` function of the `DbContext` class.